# JAXB: Problem deserializing a class B that extends a class A

Tags: java, constructor, jaxb, adapter, unmarshalling

Please consider the following example:

There is a **ClassA** and a **ClassB** which extends it. My problem is now that I have to unmarshall a **ClassB** from an xml file. Please note that **ClassA** can not be changed as it is not under my control.

Several problems are noted in this example:

The main problem is that **ClassA** does not have a default no-arg constructor which is required by JAXB without Adapter. Therefore I implemented **MyAdapter** which maps **ClassB** to the simple class **ValB** which can be processed by JAXB without any problems.

The main problem is how to make JAXB use this adapter? Neither defining the  **@XmlJavaTypeAdapter** on class level nor registering the Adapter to the unmarshaller does it.

Does anybody know how to make JAXB use **MyAdapter** so that the unmarshaller returns an object that is an instance of **ClassA**?

```
public class JaxbTest {

    public static abstract class ClassA {
        public ClassA(String id) {
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class) // does not have an effect
    public static class ClassB extends ClassA {

        public String text;

        public ClassB() {
            super("");
        }
    }

    public static class ValB {
        public String text;
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ValB, ClassB> {

        @Override
        public ClassB unmarshal(ValB v) throws Exception {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            b.text = v.text;
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public ValB marshal(ClassB v) throws Exception {
            ValB b = new ValB();
            b.text = v.text;
            return b;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassB.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setAdapter(new MyAdapter()); // does not have an effect
            ClassA a = (ClassA) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"));
            // do somthing with a
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: Don't take the code too serious - it is just an example demonstrating the problem. I know that the definition of **ClassA** and **ClassB** are not really useful.

Comment: We have addressed this issue in the upcoming EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) release.  In this release no code changes to your example are required:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459737/jaxb-problem-deserializing-a-class-b-that-extends-a-class-a/4459779#4459779

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

We have addressed this issue in the upcoming [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) 2.2.0 release (see [bug #332742](https://bugs.eclipse.org/332742)).  In this release abstract classes will not be checked for a no-arg constructor.

Pre-release versions with this fix can be obtained here starting December 18th:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**Workaround**

This is what the @XmlTransient annotation is for.  If possible do the following:

```
@XmlTransient
public static abstract class ClassA {
    public ClassA(String id) {
    }
}
```

If it is not possible to annotate ClassA directly, you could leverage an [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) extension to do this.  MOXy allows you to specify JAXB metadata as an XML file.  This is useful when you can't modify a model class:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Below are some articles explaining @XmlAdapter:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: Both articles are different because the immutable object is a field of an encapsulating class - which is not the case in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the info even if I was intending to use the JAXB version that comes with the JRE. The most interesting part of your answer is that MOXy has/had the same bug. May be this is a case that lies outside of the JAXB specification or is MOXy basing on the same sources as implementation by SUN/Oracle?

Comment: The code bases are completely independent.  Both groups just decided to do the no-arg check on all classes.  At least now in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) we have fixed it.  Thanks for identifying the issue.